# Friend template functions can't access private members

Tags: c++, templates

I have a question regarding [this](http://www.gmannickg.com/?p=59#more-59) code written by @GManNickG.

I was going to see If I really understood what was going on so I edited `print_binary_helper`'s friend functions like this (original code has been commented):

```
//template <typename U>
//friend print_binary_helper<U> print_binary(U value);
friend print_binary_helper<T> print_binary(T value);

//template <typename U>
//friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& sink,
//  const print_binary_helper<U> source);
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& sink,
    const print_binary_helper<T> source);

//template <typename U>
//friend std::wostream& operator<<(std::wostream& sink,
//  const print_binary_helper<U> source);
friend std::wostream& operator<<(std::wostream& sink,
    const print_binary_helper<T> source);
```

to use T instead of U but the program won't compile. Could someone explain to me what I did wrong and if this is even possible and if it is, how could it be done?

I'm using VC++ 11 and this is the error I get:

```
1>anything.cpp(68): error C2248: 'print_binary_helper<T>::print_binary_helper' : cannot access private member declared in class 'print_binary_helper<T>'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=int
1>          ]
1>          anything.cpp(31) : see declaration of 'print_binary_helper<T>::print_binary_helper'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=int
1>          ]
1>          anything.cpp(73) : see reference to function template instantiation 'print_binary_helper<T> print_binary<int>(T)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=int
1>          ]
1>anything.cpp(68): error C2248: 'print_binary_helper<T>::print_binary_helper' : cannot access private member declared in class 'print_binary_helper<T>'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=unsigned __int64
1>          ]
1>          anything.cpp(31) : see declaration of 'print_binary_helper<T>::print_binary_helper'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=unsigned __int64
1>          ]
1>          anything.cpp(75) : see reference to function template instantiation 'print_binary_helper<T> print_binary<unsigned __int64>(T)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=unsigned __int64
1>          ]
```

Comment: works fine on g++ 4.7.2

Answer (score 1):

```
template <typename U>
friend print_binary_helper<U> print_binary(U value);
```

makes a **template** `print_binary` function friend.

```
friend print_binary_helper<U> print_binary(U value);
```

makes a **non template** `print_binary` function friend.

The two are different. So in your case The template function is **not a friend** and the **non template function is not defined**. You don't get any errros because you are not using the non-template `print_binary` anywhere.

The functions are **friends**. So they should not depend on the template argument of the class. They should be independent functions.

---

If you want to make only `T` specializations of those functions friends to `T` specializations of the `print_binary_helper` class you can forward declare the functions and then speicalize them like you did in your class with minor modifications. Some thing like this.

```
template <typename T>
class print_binary_helper;

template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& sink,
                         const print_binary_helper<T> source);

template <typename T>
std::wostream& operator<<(std::wostream& sink,
                          const print_binary_helper<T> source);

template <typename T>
print_binary_helper<T> print_binary(T value);

template <typename T>
class print_binary_helper
{
public:
    static_assert(std::is_integral<T>::value,
                  "Cannot print non-integer in binary.");

    //make only  print_binary<T> a friend to print_binary_helper<T>
    friend print_binary_helper<T> print_binary<>(const T value);
                                //            ^^    

    friend std::ostream& operator<< <>(std::ostream& sink,
                                //  ^^
                                      const print_binary_helper<T> source);

    friend std::wostream& operator<< <>(std::wostream& sink,
                                //   ^^
                                     const print_binary_helper<T> source);
```

Here is an [**`Example`**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=92894d54bf5f5d06552475e145a8de37-50d9cfc8a1d350e7409e81e87c2653ba) of that.

Comment: Thanks! This helped me while working through an example of using a friend function with a templated class. I think the book I have is out of date.